# I want to use a batch file that make if you type "say hello" it will do echo hello

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo

Here is my batch file:

```
@echo off

:start

set /p test=">"

if "%test%" == "shutdown" do shutdown

if "%test%" == "say hello" goto echo

:echo

%echo%

goto start

:shutdown

shutdown /s

exit
```

but i want to replace the "hello" with anything the users type, can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off

:start
set /p test=">"
if "%test%" == "shutdown" goto shutdown

echo you typed: %test%
goto start

:shutdown
shutdown /s
exit
```

Comment: Can you escape the caret as well?